# Using ComboBox.Text when combobox is tied to DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

We have a project that sets the DataSource of a combobox, but allows users to either select something from this list OR type in an item not contained in the list.  Basically, there is a Geobase that contains streets, but the users are not required to choose a street from the list.  The ComboBox.DropDownStyle is set to DropDown.

If a user edits a record that contains a street NOT in the geobase (and therefore not in the ComboBox.DataSource) we are having issues populating the form correctly.

Here is a greatly simplified form of our problem:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new form.  In the constructor the DataSource of the ComboBox is set with three items:
        //      Main St., First St., and Second St.
        ComboBoxTrialForm frm = new ComboBoxTrialForm();

        // Set comboBox1.Text equal to an item NOT in the datasource
        frm.SetComboTextValue("Michigan Ave.");

        // Show the form, and the comboBox has the first item in its datasource selected
        frm.Show();
    }
```

The ComboBoxTrial Class goes something like this:

```
public partial class ComboBoxTrialForm : Form
{
    public ComboBoxTrialForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> streets = new List<string>() { "Main St.", "First St.", "Second St." };
        comboBox1.DataSource = streets;
    }

    public void SetComboTextValue(string text)
    {
        comboBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

I set break points and found that comboBox1.Text does indeed get set correctly.  Interestingly I found that the BindingContextChanged event actually gets fired twice in this simplified example.  Once in the constructor when `comboBox1.DataSource = streets` is called, and a second time when `frm.Show()` is called.

Why is this event firing when the form is shown, and is this why my manually set selection is getting removed?  How should I go about correcting this behavior?

Also, am I incorrect in thinking that I should be able to use the combobox in this way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to set the SelectedIndex to -1 so that no item is selected in the list.  I didn't have any problem getting "Michigan Ave." to display in the combo box with this method.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Main St.", "First St.", "Second St." };
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Also, you could show the form, and then set the text.  Unless that's a problem, the user probably won't notice.

```
    frm.Show();
    frm.SetComboTextValue("Michigan Ave.");
```

Comment: Thanks so much Bryan.  I really appreciate the time you took to consider my issue and provide a solution.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) states: that "Setting the Text property to a value that is not in the collection leaves the SelectedIndex unchanged."  I would assume that setting the combobox.Text to a value not in the list would leave the selectedIndex at 0.  I would think that when the form/combobox is shown it sets its value equal to the current selectedIndex, wiping out my selection.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Also, any idea why the BindingContextChanged event fires twice.  I understand why it fires the first time, but I don't get why it fires again when the form is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any instances in our winforms code where we set the datasource in the constructor, so I can't really address why you are seeing what you are seeing.

I can, however, tell you how we handle this type of issue all the time in order to avoid the inevitable timing issues: we create a method on the form that accepts the parameters that we want to use in the form, have the form show itself, then set the field values.

We started this pattern years ago when we were dealing with third-party controls that reset themselves or were in an invalid state until the form was actually visible.

This pattern is also incredibly helpful if the form decides that it should not be shown for some reason (there is another form of the same type open, there was an error accessing resources used by the form, the user doesn't have the appropriate permissions, etc).

The pattern is also useful for returning more useful values from modal dialogs than the standard built-in modal dialog values.

In your case, we would rewrite your form as follows:

```
public partial class ComboBoxTrialForm : Form
{
    public ComboBoxTrialForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowForm(string comboBoxValue)
    {
        this.Show();

        List<string> streets = new List<string>() { "Main St.", "First St.", "Second St." };
        comboBox1.DataSource = streets;

        SetComboTextValue(comboBoxValue);
    }

    public void SetComboTextValue(string text)
    {
        comboBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Your button1_click event then becomes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new form.  In the constructor the DataSource of the ComboBox is set with three items:
    //      Main St., First St., and Second St.
    ComboBoxTrialForm frm = new ComboBoxTrialForm();

    // Show the form, and the comboBox has the first item in its datasource selected
    frm.ShowForm("Michigan Ave.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting together this answer and taking the time to consider my issue.  This is a helpful pattern and certainly would solve my problem.  I'm marking @Bryan Crosby as have the correct answer, because it requires the fewest changes to our code base.  We seem to have a lot going on when the form loads up.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a combobox, why not use a WCF Windows Service that is called as the user types into a text box. That way you could use a text box, but still give the user the ability to choose something similar from the database

This should give you the code for the windows service

http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Windows-Service-Hosting.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

And you could call it from a keyup event.

Comment: I would assume this is for ASP.NET stuff, right?  We are using winforms on this project.

Comment: @errorstacks Sorry misread. The same thing could be achieved with a WCF service to supply the list of addresses.

Comment: Ahhh.. okay, So not Ajax but WCF.  I will look into those links and consider that possibility.  But we do like that they can see the options in the dropdown.  Also, we have subclassed the combobox to do a 'typeahead' feature on the keyup, looking if items match what is in the list.